# How do you repeat rows in a table multiple time

Tags: dax

I created a table a DAX Studio and want to repeat all the rows (with all the columns) in a new table multiple times; to my choosing.

```
//create temp table of Historic Facilities for all annual groups 1 to 3            
 TABLE HistFac =
    ADDCOLUMNS ( FacSchHist,
       "Rank", RANKX ( FacSchHist, [WtAvg] ),        
       "Annual Group", (RANKX ( FacSchHist, [WtAvg] ) - FLOOR((RANKX ( FacSchHist, [WtAvg] ) - 1) /3 * 3,3)))

EVALUATE
NonHistFac
ORDER BY [Annual Group],
[WtAvg] DESC
```

I want the maintain the original order in the repeated list.  There are obviously many ways to construct a table (see code above); however, how does one repeat the list of rows?

Thanks you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the filters that are affecting the measure inside RANKX because of the context transition coming from the table provide in the first argument of GENERATE

```
DEFINE
    TABLE HistFac =
        GENERATE (
            { 1, 2, 3 },
            ADDCOLUMNS (
                ADDCOLUMNS (
                    FacSchHist,
                    "@Rank",
                        RANKX (
                            FacSchHist,
                            CALCULATE ( [WtAvg], REMOVEFILTERS ( TableSupliedInTheFirstArgument ) )
                        )
                ),
                "Annual Group",
                    [@Rank]
                        - FLOOR ( ( [@Rank] - 1 ) / 3 * 3, 3 )
            )
        )
EVALUATE
NonHistFac
ORDER BY
    [Annual Group],
    [WtAvg] DESC
```

Or simply use variables to compute in a different filter context.

```
DEFINE
    TABLE HistFac =
        VAR RankedTable =
            ADDCOLUMNS ( FacSchHist, "@Rank", RANKX ( FacSchHist, [WtAvg] ) )
        VAR SomeCalculationOnRankedTable =
            ADDCOLUMNS (
                RankedTable,
                "Annual Group",
                    [@Rank]
                        - FLOOR ( ( [@Rank] - 1 ) / 3 * 3, 3 )
            )
        RETURN
            GENERATE ( { 1, 2, 3 }, SomeCalculationOnRankedTable )
EVALUATE
NonHistFac
ORDER BY
    [Annual Group],
    [WtAvg] DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GENERATE for repeating the rows:

```
DEFINE
    TABLE HistFac =
        GENERATE (
            { 1, 2, 3 },
            ADDCOLUMNS (
                FacSchHist,
                "Rank", RANKX ( FacSchHist, [WtAvg] ),
                "Annual Group",
                    (
                        RANKX ( FacSchHist, [WtAvg] )
                            - FLOOR ( ( RANKX ( FacSchHist, [WtAvg] ) - 1 ) / 3 * 3, 3 )
                    )
            )
        )
EVALUATE
NonHistFac
ORDER BY
    [Annual Group],
    [WtAvg] DESC
```

A better way to write this code will be to use nested ADDCOLUMNS:

```
DEFINE
    TABLE HistFac =
        GENERATE (
            { 1, 2, 3 },
            ADDCOLUMNS (
                ADDCOLUMNS ( FacSchHist, "@Rank", RANKX ( FacSchHist, [WtAvg] ) ),
                "Annual Group",
                    [@Rank]
                        - FLOOR ( ( [@Rank] - 1 ) / 3 * 3, 3 )
            )
        )
EVALUATE
NonHistFac
ORDER BY
    [Annual Group],
    [WtAvg] DESC
```

Comment: AntrikshSharma - I will give those a try now , appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

AntrikshSharma - I will give those a try now , appreciate your guidance.

Okay, the code worked fine; but uncovered a problem.  After the initial ranking of the list, and before the replication - I do not want to continue ranking.

In other words, I want the initial ranked-list to be reproduced 3x without any further ranking; just have each duplicated occurrence appear after the initial list in the exact order.

If the initial list was 12345, then 12345,12345,12345 - thank you for the more efficient code as well.

Answer (score 0):

AntrikshSharma, your comment and code, "Or simply use variables to compute in a different filter context" is genius.  The code performed as expected.  The problem I'm experiencing is with the UNION of the two tables "NonHistFac" and "HistFac". I will provide an image to explain then the most current code.

[15yr cycle of Hist & NonHist Facilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13jut.jpg)

The image shows the goal.  combine the NonHistFac  (all surveyed every 5yrs) with the HistFac (all surveyed every 3yrs).  The original ranking must be maintained (this is currently met.)

Here is the problem.  The numbers within the image are the Values as produced by the GENERATE function.  When the tables are combined and the NonHistFac are mixed with the HistFac, they are not evenly distributed throughout the 1 to 5 Values.

What appears in Values 4 and 5 is obviously the remaining HistFac.  I need to have the entire combination distributed from 1 to 5; or as shown, over the 15 year cycle.

Thank you.

```
// produce non-historic table with additional columns and replicate all rows 3x
TABLE NonHistFac =
        VAR NonHistRankedTable =
            ADDCOLUMNS ( FacSchNonHist, "@Rank", RANKX ( FacSchNonHist, [WtAvg] ) )
        VAR NonHistAnnualizedRankedTable =
            ADDCOLUMNS (
                NonHistRankedTable,
                "Annual Group",
                    [@Rank] - FLOOR ( ( [@Rank] - 1 ) / 5 * 5, 5 )
            )
        RETURN
            GENERATE ( { 1, 2, 3 }, NonHistAnnualizedRankedTable )
            // from the FLOOR & GENERATE functions, 5 x 3 = 15 (this is a 15 year cycle)

 //produce historic facility table with additional columns and replicate all rows 5x
TABLE HistFac =
        VAR HistRankedTable =
            ADDCOLUMNS ( FacSchHist, "@Rank", RANKX ( FacSchHist, [WtAvg] ) )
        VAR HistAnnualizedRankedTable =
            ADDCOLUMNS (
                HistRankedTable,
                "Annual Group",
                    [@Rank] - FLOOR ( ( [@Rank] - 1 ) / 3 * 3, 3 )
            )
        RETURN
            GENERATE ( { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, HistAnnualizedRankedTable )
            // from the FLOOR & GENERATE functions, 3 x 5 = 15 (this is a 15 year cycle)

// combine the tables NonHistFac & HistFac to create one-table representing a 15 yr cycle
VAR FacSchUnion =
    UNION(
        NonHistFac,
        HistFac
    )
VAR FacSch15yr =
    DISTINCT(FacSchUnion)

EVALUATE
FacSch15yr

ORDER BY [Value],
[Annual Group],
[WtAvg] DESC
```